# Responsive Development - Don't load 'id' instead of display none

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I have seen some really cool mobile responsive websites that look perfect from a UI standpoint, then when the browser is scaled to desktop size it looks perfect also.

When I have developed starting with a mobile first approach my desktop layout always lacks content because it was built with a mobile first approach.

So for example take a look at the Land Rover website: http://www.landrover.co.uk/index.html

As you can see the mobile website is completely different to the desktop site. They have a video that loads on the desktop but not the mobile dimensions.

If I don't want to display a certain section within my mobile dimensions such as a navbar that has a HTML structure that I could not style for the mobile I usually use a media query to display none on that section. The issue with this is that it still loads and if you do this to many elements on a page it soon makes your mobile layout quiet heavy as it is loading content that it wont use.

So my question is how do I stop certain elements loading until the browser has been scaled up or down? I can see that Land Rover stops their Video's from loading when you scale down the browser however when you scale it up the video loads.

I'm sure this is probably done with JS however I am unsure what is the best practice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Well you can write a small script which basically does the same except it loads instead of hides. (function () {

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();



if (viewportWidth > 1400) {

$('#wrapper').load('/ajax/largeScreen.php');

} else {

$('#wrapper').load('/ajax/smallScreen.php');

}

}());

Comment: Or take a look at this plugin, used it a while back when I had the same problem as you have now. https://github.com/Podders/Jquery-Media-Comments/

Comment: I think window.matchMedia() is exactly what you want.  I'm not sure why my answer got downvoted!  It uses media query syntax, but gives you the conditional loading that css media queries don't give you.

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally load your content after a successful check of mobile/non-mobile browser.

The following is from a similar question, it provides true or false based on whether you're in a mobile environment. Insert your logic within your function after a conditional check of this function.

**EDIT** I refuse to provide full-source code, implement the solution you've asked for yourself.

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Most developers I know use a web framework to do all the hard work.  The two most complete and well known frameworks are:

- Zurb Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/)

The specific mechanisms to do what you are asking are specific to those frameworks.  I have experience with Zurb, but Bootstrap is equally powerful and you may find more resources (books, etc.) for that framework.

Both have a "gridded" layout system where you can set different column definitions for "Large", "Medium" and "Small" profiles.  Both also have the equivalent of a menu bar that collapses into a fairly standard app menu for a phone.  I would start with one of those, as it really does make the process of designing a responsive app much less painless.

Comment: I believe he's asking for a solution to prevent not only the display, but the loading, (hence the mention of a weighing-down) of his content.

Answer (score -3):

You can take advantage of NON-CSS media queries to give you control in your Javascript.  This gives you the opportunity to conditionally load heavy-weight items are you like:

```
window.matchMedia(put your css media query here)
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries4.shtml

You can use these to make it responsive:

addListener( functionref)

removeListener(functionref)

Answer (score -3):

you want to use media queries for responsive website and web applications.

Most of the time, however, you will use a css framework as Berin has mentioned. There may be time where you will need custom styles!

`<p class="my-text>Hello world </p>`

**Your css file will for example be:**

```
/* On Mobile, text is red */
@media screen and (min-width:480px) { .my-text { color:red; } }

/* On tablet, text is blue */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (min-width:1024px) { .my-text { color:blue; } }

 /* On Desktop, text is grey */    
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .my-text { color:grey; } }
```

Please refer to the following [documentation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for comprehension media queries according to device.

Comment: He knows about the media queries, he is asking for another solution.